# php debug_backtrace() to string with some objects inside the result

Tags: php, arrays, set, debug-backtrace

I want to debug an application with debug_backtrace() in the __set function.

As I need it as a string I tried it with `$myStringVar = print_r(debug_backtrace(),true);`

But this doesn't work. I found out that there are some objects in my array that debug_backtrace() returns.

So I have to convert it another way to a string with ignoring the objects.

But how to do this?

Comment: You can call `debug_backtrace(0)` to avoid objects. Anyway `debug_backtrace` returns arrays, not strings: see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) for more details!

Comment: Hi, tried it with debug_backtrace(0) but it seems it crashes again when calling print_r(debug_backtrace(0),true). I've put it into a try catch(\Exception $e) to get all Exceptions but it doesn't get into the catch, it just stops.

Comment: Are You sure that `__set()` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Use http_build_query, ie

```
$mysStringVar = http_build_query(debug_backtrace());
```

Comment: Devpro, what was your edit?  It looks like you rewrote what I wrote.

Comment: if I use http_build_query(debug_backtrace)); $myStringVar contains only "Evaluating..." which is no useable backtrace for me :/